# How to access properties of Datastore query (App Engine, python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm going nuts trying to access the properties of a Datastore query. I could not find anything in the documentation (it could be me).

In the datastore I have the following:

[image]

Here's a snippet of my main.py:

```
import all the necessary stuff
...
datastore_client = datastore.Client()
u_name = 'batman' # example of the user I want to find
qn = datastore_client.query(kind='user').add_filter('user_id', '=', u_name).fetch()
```

So far so good, but how do I access the properties of this query?

What I haven't been able to find is how do I access the first_name of user 'batman'?
Something like:

```
name = qn.somefuntion('first_name')
```

Could someone tell me how to do this and also point me to the respective documentation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [python library reference for an Entity](https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/entities.html). The key part there is "you can treat an entity like a regular Python dictionary."

```
for entity in qn:
    print(entity['first_name'])
```